# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365

I am writing a code to retrieve data from SP lists. But when I try to deploy my solution through VS 2013 it says

> Server Error in '/MyApp' Application: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can someone help me?

```
var spContext2 = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
            using (var clientContext2 = spContext2.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {              
                clientContext2.Load(clientContext2.Web, web => web.Title, web => web.Created);
                clientContext2.ExecuteQuery();
                ListCollection lists = clientContext2.Web.Lists;
                List list = lists.GetByTitle("Annonces");
                clientContext2.Load<List>(list);
                clientContext2.ExecuteQuery();
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext2.Load<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection>(items);
                clientContext2.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Is there a list with the title of "Annonces" in the host web?

Comment: yes ,there is a list "Annonces" in the host web. it says that the problem is in that line of my code  "using (var clientContext2 = spContext2.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())" knowing that I used the same code in another page (.aspx) and it retrieves list correctly.

Comment: Are you forwaring all needed query parameters to this page though?

Comment: I didn't understand you!